# Android lollipop show notification, if beacon in specific range

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android

Could anyone please share any steps to show notification when beacon came in specific range in android lollipop.

Comment: what have u tried so far..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the [Android Beacon Library](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library) with code like this:

```
    @Override
    public void didRangeBeaconsInRegion(Collection<Beacon> beacons, Region region) {
            for (Beacon beacon: beacons) {
                    if (beacon.getDistance() < 5.0) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "I see a beacon that is less than 5 meters away.");
                            NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
                                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                  .setContentTitle("Beacon Reference Application")
                                  .setContentText("An beacon is nearby.")
                                  .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

                            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
                            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(new Intent(this, MonitoringActivity.class));
                            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                            stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                               0,
                               PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                            );
                            builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
                            NotificationManager notificationManager =
                                   (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                            notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());                        
                    }
            }
    }
```

Full details here:

http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/distance-triggering.html

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the tutorial: http://developer.estimote.com/eddystone/ to get started. Then you can retrieve info about signal like this:

```
Beacon nearestbeacon;

(...) 

// computeAccuracy gives you distance in meters
Utils.computeAccuracy(nearestBeacon);

// computeProximity gives you state like IMMEDIATE/NEAR/FAR
Utils.computeProximity(nearestBeacon);
```